# Error generated by named arguments and argument unpacking in function call not throwing ErrorException in PHP-8

Tags: php, docker, terminal, php-8

The following code works as expected: throws the ErrorException and calls the shutdown function for the fatal-error generated by `require`

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    echo "anyway, hello world\n";
});

set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
});

set_exception_handler(function($exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
});

require "unavailable_file";
```

**Output:**

> require(unavailable_file): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> anyway, hello world

But fatal error generated by named arguments fails to call the exception-handler and the shutdown function

```
// replacing require in the previous code with the following

function foo() {}

foo(...[], bar: "baz");
```

**Output:**

> Fatal error: Cannot combine named arguments and argument unpacking

Combining all of them also is not working as expected and the `ErrorException` from `require` is  not caught

```
// ... 

require "unavailable_file";

function foo() {}

foo(...[], bar: "baz");
```

**Output:**

> Fatal error: Cannot combine named arguments and argument unpacking

So is this another bug or am I missing something here?

**PS:** The PHP version is 8.0.0RC2 (cli)

Comment: Have a look at https://phppot.com/php/php-errors/

Comment: I may be wrong. It seems that `foo(...[], bar: "baz")` is causing compile time error when script is not executed yet and shutdown functions are not registered. `require "unavailable_file"` seems to cause runtime error when script is executing and shutdown functions are registered. Compile errors are reported before runtime errors as compilation is performed before execution of code.

Comment: @Rain. Thankyou for pointing that out. I found something else. From [Manual](https://www.php.net/language.errors.basics#language.errors.basics.user): If PHP's default error handling is inadequate, you can also handle many types of error with your own custom error handler by installing it with set_error_handler(). **While some error types cannot be handled this way**, those that can be handled can then be handled in the way that your script sees fit: for example, this can be used to show a custom error page to the user and then report more directly than via a log, such as by sending an e-mail.

Comment: @UmairKhan Since it's not a parse/syntax error, so the shutdown function should have been be called like in the case of other compile time errors. AFAIK, only syntax errors in the executed script prevent shutdown whereas even those in included files don't. Can you provide any other example which **prevents shutdown** from being called, otherwise this probably is a bug

Comment: Hey I found an example. See [here](https://3v4l.org/e2G6d). If I add `void` as return type for `abc` function. Shutdown function is not executed and error is displayed.

Comment: @UmairKhan Although our example is missing the `register_shutdown_function()`, thanks for the example. It really is the case of different type of fatal errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it was indeed the case of different fatal type of fatal errors.

Since this falls under the category "generated before script is executed", unfortunately the shutdown function will never be called. Too bad I did't find anything showing which fatal errors fall under this category.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it turns out this is not a bug!

Errors of type `E_COMPILE_ERROR`

> Fatal compile-time errors. This is like an E_ERROR, except it is
> generated by the Zend Scripting Engine

And also `E_PARSE`

> Compile-time parse errors. Parse errors should only be generated by
> the parser

Are the only reason for such behavior (plus if the process is killed with a SIGTERM, or SIGKILL signal or `exit` or `die` were called before the shutdown function)

Here is a list of such errors

1. https://3v4l.org/oO4L7 => Redeclaration of a function
2. https://3v4l.org/cNHbu => `private` abtract methods
3. https://3v4l.org/jPpIU =>  Acess level must be the same or less restrictive